# Android 4.1 ImageView

Tags: android

This code works fine on all versions of Android, but not in Android 4.1

//I run it on emulator.

Image `img_1.png` exists in folder `/res/drawable/`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

LinearLayout llMain = new LinearLayout(this);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
llMain.setLayoutParams(lp);

ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
int resid = getResources().getIdentifier("img_1", "drawable", getPackageName());        
Drawable imageDrw = getResources().getDrawable(resid);
iv.setImageDrawable(imageDrw);                      

    llMain.addView(iv); 

setContentView(llMain);
}
```

Why?

Comment: Did you tried `Drawable imageDrw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_1);` ?

Comment: what do you mean by not work, Does it crash? Describe the problem

Comment: When i run it on Android 2.3 and other i can see image.
But when i run it on Android 4.1 i see only black screen.
to shkschneider: getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_1) doesn't work too on Android 4.1

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working fine in 4.1

```
relative.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getIdentifier(
            "image", "drawable", "com.package.application"));
```

So you can set

```
iv.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(
                "image", "drawable", "com.package.application"))
```

Comment: I try to use - relative.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getIdentifier(             "image", "drawable", "com.package.application")) - doesn't work, try - relative.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_1)) - doesn't work. I use SDK Tools r20.0.1. Who can try my code on 4.1? Is it only my bug?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and I solved it by moving the image to `drawable-xhdpi`.

Maybe there are some problems in transfering the image size from smaller dpi in Android 4.1.